# select list items dynamically javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, json, dynamic

Is it possible to dynamically pass information from a dynamically created option dropdown list.  All the Option's are created from a JSON call.  The end goal would be to pass the ID to another JSON call to retrieve data. I'm currently using a switch based on each id#...would that be the only way?

HTML:

```
<option id="-1">DEVELOPER GROUP</option>
```

The numbers increase up to 5 for now but we are adding more groups daily

JS:

```
$("#fDistList").change(function () {
var id = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("id");

switch (id) {
    case "-1":
        console.log("Developer Group has been selected");
        break;
```

Comment: Why not using the attribute value ? Especially for an option.

Comment: you can just do the console log without the switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `value` of the options to the value you want to pass to the other call.

```
<option value="yourvalue">DEVELOPER GROUP</option>
```

Then all you'd have to do is

```
$("#fDistList").change(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
```

Assuming `#fDistList` is you select.

Comment: that was it that's working perfectly, I'm building the other half of the JSON call now. Thanks